# Operation along third dimension of two 3-D arrays in R

Tags: r, arrays

I have two 3D arrays, the dimensions are specifically `[Longitudes][Latitudes][Time]` and the two array are temperature and precipitation observations in space and time.

I would like to obtain a 2D matrix `[Longitudes][Latitudes]` of the correlation (along the `[Time]` dimension) between the temperature and precipitation array for each specific Longitude-Latitude point.

The function `apply()` only work with one array at the time and the only solution I came out with is a basic loop, being `Ts` and `Ps` respectively the Temperature and Precipitation 3D arrays this is what I wrote:

```r
corr.matix <- array(dim = dim(Ts)[c(1,2)])
  for (i in seq(dim(Ts)[1])){
    for (j in seq(dim(Ts)[2])){
      corr.matix[i,j] <- cor(Ts[i,j,],Ps[i,j,])
    }
  }
```

It works, however it is slow.

My question is, is there a faster (vectorised?) way to solve this simple problem in R?

Answer (score 0):

It would help to have some sample working code to test, but could `map2()` from package `purrr`help?

See https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map2.html